# Playback rate doesn't change for Chromecast Ultra

Tags: casting, chromecast, receiver

I have been working on app, which has possiblity to cast video to chromecast devices. And we have such problem: we need to change playback rate and it works  for Chromecast 2.0 (as needed), and doesn't work for Chromecast Ultra (playback rate as default).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bohdan_player.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audioPlayer" src="https://www2.iis.fraunhofer.de/AAC/ChID-BLITS-EBU-Narration.mp4" autoplay controls></audio>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("audioPlayer").playbackRate = 1.5;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please open a ticket on our SDK issue tracker so we can address this.

Comment: Hi, @AliNaddaf. Thank you for response. I already did it: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=1139